# Unable to get 3 child processes from 2 forks()

Tags: c, unix

I just stepped into C and currently, I am trying to code the resultants of using 2 `forks()` in which it should give me 4 processes, and 3 of them are the child processes.

In the following code, I am however only about 2 get 2 child processes instead of the expected 3. I read that the number of processes is determined by 2^n and minus 1 to get the child processes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork(); // fork #1
    pid = fork(); // fork #2

    if (pid==0)
    {
        printf("Child process.\n");
        printf("  |-- Child PID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("  |-- Parent PID: %d\n", getppid());
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        printf("Parent process\n");
        printf("  |-- Parent PID: %d\n", getpid());
        printf("  |-- Child PID: %d\n", pid);

        printf("\tWait till the child process is finished...\n");
        sleep(100);
        printf("\tChild process is now finished.\n");
        
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Fork return error code. No child process.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output result based on the code I have written:

```
Parent process
    |-- Parent PID: 3201
    |-- Child PID: 3203
        Wait till the child process is finished...
Child process
    |-- Child PID: 3203
    |-- Parent PID: 3201
Parent process
    |-- Parent PID: 3202
    |-- Child PID: 3204
        Wait till the child process is finished...
Child process
    |-- Child PID: 3203
    |-- Parent PID: 3201
            Child process is now finished.
            Child process is now finished.
```

Am I perhaps missing something that could have resulted in the missing child process?

Comment: one of your "parent processes" is a child of the other, you just don't print that fact.

Comment: @user253751 can I trouble you to share more insights with me on that? I can't really see which line in my code is contributing to that

Comment: Also realize that you are overwriting the stored value of `pid`when you call `pid = fork();` twice.

Comment: @dissidia with regard to @user253751's statement, when you call `pid = fork()` that spawns a child process. You then have 2 processes. Then both of those processes call `pid = fork()`, meaning the original parent now has two children, and the first child now has a child.

Comment: and both of those processes store the relationship from their second fork in `pid` and forget whether they were the first or second child from the first fork

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `pid` before inferring what happened.

```
pid_t pid;
pid = fork(); // fork #1
pid = fork(); // fork #2

if (pid==0) ...
```

Instead, check `pid` after each `fork()`.

```
pid_t pid;
int tag = 0;

pid = fork(); // fork #1
if (pid==0) tag = 2;
pid = fork(); // fork #2
if (pid==0) ++tag;

printf("tag: %d\n", tag);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCsIwEEX3OcWnRUio2tqlMZ5EkJKYOqip1HQlnj1OiiAu3Ax/3n/M2FVvbSop2OvkTtg9oqNhfd6LL5oCMc1MUIi4dRQgFZ7pTu4YwVPPRex6GDRaCEac/DBepNKo6zmi3AjykFwa06iP3up/dvtjVxX7@fTIr7wseNti4Q6hWOZLSqdXegM)